# Bijection Proof on

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help me prove this? This is what I have so far.

[image]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation should help you make this more readable to us. What is $W$? I suspect it's $\mathbb N$ but I can't see that from your notes.

Comment: I apologize, my W here stands for whole numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to split the mapping based on even $k$ and odd $k$. We have
$$f(k) = 
\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{k+1}2 & \text{ if $k$ is odd}\\
\dfrac{k}2 & \text{ if $k$ is even}
\end{cases}
$$
Now if $f(k_1) = f(k_2)$, we trivially have $k_1 = k_2$ and hence the function is injective.

Further, given any integer $z$, if $z\geq 0$, we have $f(2z) = z$. If $z < 0$, we have $f(-2z-1) = z$. Hence, the map is also surjective.